# How can I see how many people downloaded my app on the Amazon AppStore?

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

Do they have a statistics page with details about how many downloaded the app etc. Or do I have to use an analytics service?

Comment: it seems like event today amazon has no support like google console has. answers below are only when you integrate amazon analytics into your app which is not even free to use in 2017 where all others (google, Microsoft etc) offers free service

Answer (score 16):

After logging in to the Amazon Developer Portal, navigate to 'Reporting' in the top nav and then 'Engagement' in the subnav.

Comment: this should be the answer.  Engagements was added around May 2013.

Comment: This is when you enable Amazon analytics but question is simple download count like on google console

Answer (score 6):

**[Link Updated]**
From the Amazon Developer console, visit the [sales link](https://developer.amazon.com/reporting/console/appstore/overview) to see the number of downloads of an app. Amazon uses sales for app download count. On the Sales page, you will see the number of downloads per market i.e uk, india etc listed for you. 
The Engagement page is for Amazon Mobile Analytics which is not what you required. 
Hope this help someone

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to https://developer.amazon.com/
2. Login using your account
3. Click on Developer Console
4. Click on Reporting

   In the Overview section it will show you the number of units sold. This is Amazon's term for downloads.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to log into the [Amazon developer portal](https://developer.amazon.com/home.html)

[App Annie](https://www.appannie.com) support Amazon analytics so you may find it easier to use them.

Answer (score 0):

After logging in to the Amazon Developer Portal click on REPORTING, then click on Engagement beta ...
**they provide twelve months of Free access to the AWS**
[AWS|Amazon Mobile Analytics](https://aws.amazon.com/mobileanalytics/)